# Question on: gradient & laplace operator

Tags: partial-differential-equations, laplacian

given the function $f(x,y,) = x^2-y^2$.

the gradient should be given by $grad f = (2x, -2y)$.

If I'm drawing single of these vectors, I only get the ones on the positive x-axis. Is this correct?

And what does the laplace operator tell me?  In this case it is $f_{xx} + f_{yy} = 2-2 = 0$. So at ANY point of this function the divergence of the gradient is zero?

Thank you very much :)

Comment: What do you mean by divergence of a function?

Comment: Sorry, I mean the divergence of the gradient of the function (as described here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_operator )

Comment: Ok, so in this case the answer is yes. It's true for any function $f$ that satisfies $\Delta f = 0$.

Comment: Ok, but what does that mean? I know what the gradient does, but not what the laplace operator exactly means.